# React Recompose Initial state value form Async Source

Tags: reactjs, recompose

In the following example in `recompose`, `withState` has an initial value of empty string. What if you needed a value form a database or dynamic source, how would you have it update on that prop change?

For example:

```
withState('value', 'updateValue', (user) => user.name)
```

Original code from `recompose`;

```
const enhance = compose(
  withState('value', 'updateValue', ''),
  withHandlers({
    onChange: props => event => {
      props.updateValue(event.target.value)
    },
    onSubmit: props => event => {
      event.preventDefault()
      submitForm(props.value)
    }
  })
)

const Form = enhance(({ value, onChange, onSubmit }) =>
  <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
    <label>Value
      <input type="text" value={value} onChange={onChange} />
    </label>
  </form>
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Given the example above, I just branched;

**v4** I just seem to have race conditions so I made sure that these specific components wouldn't render until it's considered done loading. Now I can go back to the original code;

**v3** The following works, and perhaps their is a better way or tools I could be using within recompose.

```
withState('value', 'updateValue', ''),
withPropsOnChange(['name'], (props) => assign(props, { value: props.name })),
```

**v2** By removing `branch` and adding `withPropsOnChange` I was able to achieve what I wanted. (or so it seemed)

```
withPropsOnChange(['name'], ({ name }) => ({ name })),
withState('nameValue', 'updateNameValue', ({ name }) => name ),
```

**v1** First Attempt: (Did not work out too well)

```
const enhance = compose(
  branch(
    ({ name }) => !name,
    renderNothing
  )
  withState('value', 'updateValue', ({ name }) => name),
  withHandlers({
    onChange: props => event => {
      props.updateValue(event.target.value)
    },
    onSubmit: props => event => {
      event.preventDefault()
      submitForm(props.value)
    }
  })
)

const Form = enhance(({ value, onChange, onSubmit }) =>
  <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
    <label>Value
      <input type="text" value={value} onChange={onChange} />
    </label>
  </form>
)
```

Comment: An issue pop-ed up from the above implementation, if the `name` property does not exist the form would never load for a user that never has the name property created.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the value asynchronously below the state, and then call the updater.
[React Docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) suggest to do these things in `componentDidMount`

```js
const enhancer = compose(
  withState('value', 'updateValue', ({ name }) => name),
  withHandlers({
    onChange: props => event => {
      props.updateValue(event.target.value)
    },
    onSubmit: props => event => {
      event.preventDefault()
      submitForm(props.value)
    }
  }),
  lifecycle({
    componentDidMount () {
      fetchName().then(this.props.updateValue)
    }
  }),
  branch(({ name }) => !name, () => null)
)
```

Comment: @lsaddo yea, thanks for this and linking to the docs. I usually try to avoid the lifecycle, but this makes sense.